# swift: how to calculate the date interval (today~specified day)

Tags: xcode, swift, datepicker, nsdate

Days from the date that the current intervals specified,

*for example:* Specified dates = `15/01/2016`, Today = `03/01/2016`
*Expected results:* should display **After 12 days**

Comment: Can you show us what have you already tried?

Comment: look at https://github.com/tschmitz/DateIntervalOperators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this extension:

```
extension NSDate{

    func relativeDaysFromToday()->String
    {
        let now = NSDate()

            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let unitFlags:NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.Day
            let components = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: now, toDate: self, options: [])
            return "After \(components.day) days"
    }
}

let jan2 = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 24*60*60*5)

jan2.relativeDaysFromToday()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let startDateString = "03/01/2016" // start date
let endDateString = "15/01/2016" // end date

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(startDateString)!
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(endDateString)!

let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = gregorian?.components(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: .MatchFirst)

let day = components?.day
if day == 0 {
  print( "Today")
} else {
  print( "After\(Int64(day!)) day(s)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it was not resolved.
Perhaps the problem is estimated to have occurred in the process of getting a date from the core data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `NSDateFormatter()`... and `NSCalendar()`... try something like this:

```
let start = "03/01/2016" 
let end = "15/01/2016"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end)!

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let unit:NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.Day
let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
```

If I understood you wrong, please feel free to correct me. Best Regards, Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for Swift 5:

```
func DateFormat() -> DateFormatter {
    let x = DateFormatter()
    x.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    x.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    return x
}

func secondsToDays (seconds : Int) -> (Int) {
    return (seconds / 86400)
}

var dates: Date?
var today: Date?

dates = DateFormat().date(from: "15/01/2016")
today = DateFormat().date(from: "17/01/2016")

let timeInterval = Int(exactly: (today?.timeIntervalSince(dates!))!) ?? 0
print("After", secondsToDays(seconds: timeInterval), "days" ) //After 2 days
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use next method for calculation.

```
func relativeDaysFromToday(startDate: Date, endDate: Date)->String
{
let diffComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
let days = diffComponents.day
return "After \(days ?? 0) days"
}
```